# Views: Arrange table elements

Tags: views

I'm having problems with arranging elements in a Views Table and I hope you can help me with it. 
Instead of rendering each field in a separate column, I'd like to group some of them together in the same column as  shown below:
[image]

Comment: Can you just combine them using a "Global: Custom text" field using replacement patterns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to @Felix Eve.... Adding more details so that it will be helpful for others..

- Edit Size & Price fields and check Exclude Checkbox
- Create Global: Custom Text field **below above fields** so that you can use replacement patterns
- Label it as Description
- Use Replacement patterns in "Global : Custom Text" something like below .. Use correct tokens from replacement patterns

  Size : [field:size]
  Price: [field:price]

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly! Only ome minor changes are needed: the format is field_size, and a <br> is needed